# How to install mysql on linux machine

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, apt-get

How to install mysql on Linux machine ?

1. I tried with `'sudo apt-get install mysql-server'` , but it resulted
   into `E: Unable to locate package mysql-server`.
2. Downloaded `mysql-server_5.7.18-1ubuntu16.10_amd64.deb-bundle.tar` , how do i install it ???
3. After successful installation, other machines should
       be able to access to this DB. How to do that ? Any server concept ?

Could you please help me here ?

Comment: Normally you can install with apt. Did you update apt

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/216287/unable-to-install-files-with-apt-get-unable-to-locate-package

Comment: yeah, tried that 'sudo apt-get update' but could see these kind of errors ignored, some files not found & index failed to download.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading the tarball, unpack it with the following command:

```
shell> tar -xvf mysql-server_5.7.18-1ubuntu16.10_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
```

Note: The exact file name can differ (version).

You may need to install the libaio library if it is not already present on your system:

```
shell> sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

Preconfigure the MySQL server package with the following command:

```
shell> sudo dpkg-preconfigure mysql-community-server_5.7.18.deb
```

Please check the following reference for more details

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-debian.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the "Universe" repository on your machine and then do an apt-get update before installing. Follow this guide if you're unsure.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine#Adding_the_Universe_and_Multiverse_Repositories

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo ufw allow mysql
systemctl start mysql
sudo /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password('set_new_password') where user='root';
sudo mysql -u root -p
enter your new password
```

booom done!

Answer (score 0):

Noob here, who needed something similar.

1. Check https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-latest-mysql-on-debian-10
   This solved the "Unable to locate package mysql-server" bit for me.
2. The link also explains how to directly install the package on CLI using wget, instead of downloading a package.
3. Check if port 3306 (or whichever port your MySQL server is configured to) on the machine that MySQL is installed on, is open and listening.
   You could check this from a remote machine using
   `nc -vz <ip address of mysql server> <port number>`  or even using telnet.

Create a user on mysql, and grant suitable permissions:
`mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
`mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'%';`
(The % symbol implies that users from any IP can access this database)

You might need to configure mysql-connector on the remote machine, if you're using python to connect to this database. Here's a simple check to see if you're connected:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='YOUR_MYSQL_IP_ADDRESS',
                                        port = 3306,
                                         database='YOUR_DB_NAME',
                                         user='YOUR_USERNAME',
                                         password='YOUR_PASSWORD',
                                         charset = 'utf8mb4',
                                         )
    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)

except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)

finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Else, if you're just looking to connect to your mysql server remotely using the terminal, you might have to install mysql-client first. After this, you could:
`mysql -h <YOUR_MYSQL_IP_ADDRESS> -u <YOUR_USERNAME> -p <YOUR_PASSWORD> <YOUR_DB_NAME>`